# Why doesn’t מזמור שיר ליום השבת mention Shabbos?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, tehilim-psalms

The song of the day for Shabbos is  מזמור שיר ליום השבת. Yet it doesn’t seem to mention Shabbos at all! Why is this?

Also, why does this Tehillim refer to a specific day of the week at all?

Comment: Do the other psalms of the day mention their day?

Comment: I am asking specifically because it is says ליום השבת. The other song of the days don’t start by saying ״ מזמור שיר ליום ״פלוני.

Comment: See RH 31a, where both opinions indicate that the "L'yom HaShabbos" is not referring to it being the mizmor for our Shabbos, but either that it is a mizmor for a) The World to Come that is 'all Shabbos', or b) Hashem's resting on the first 7th day. We say it on Shabbos as it is connected, but it isn't actually referring to the weekday.

Comment: does Mizmor L'dovid mention Dovid?

Comment: @rosends No - but it's just composed by him. Assuming the Mizmor Shir L'Yom HaShabbos is referring to Shabbos, it should have some mention of the subject it was composed for.

Comment: @AKA you mean like מִזְמוֹר שִׁיר־חֲנֻכַּת הַבַּֽיִת לְדָוִד

Comment: @rosends - that's a better example and the question would also be relevant there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Brisker Rov in his second piece on Chumash asks and answers your question.

My understanding of his answer is, that this was said by Adam on the first Shabbos. He was praising the complete creation of the world and all it's details, which was realized only when Shabbos started. That is why it is a Mizmor for the Shabbos day.

[image: Copy of the piece in the sefer]

Answer (score 1):

Rav Hutner explains that the Chumash tells us Hashem saw all He created was good, and then rested and sanctified the Seventh Day as Shabbos. Likewise, we celebrate Shabbos with the understanding that everything Hashem does in This World is good. Therefore, the second pasuk in perek 92 states, “It’s good to thank Hashem…” The whole chapter continues with this theme of goodness, wherein Hashem punishes the wicked and the righteous flourish.